# Should i need to open port for outgoing request?

Tags: http, networking, network-protocols, portforwarding

Hey can any one tell me should i need open a port for outgoing request on http?

Comment: Is this a question about a firewall, NAT, proxy, VPN, or other type of networking device? "Open a port" has a lot of potential meanings. If firewall, then the answer below is accurate (+1 to it). If something else, then it may not be.

Comment: This is a better question for superuser.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your firewall might block outgoing connections on port 80 but this is quite rare.
So, the answer is "probably, but unlikely"